# Multiple user login at same time using jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

I had created a simple website that user can login based on their user name and password and goes to the homepage of that user.
If I login with user1 in first tab of browser it goes to the homepage of user1.
then again in another tab if I login with another user2 it reaches the homepage of that user2.
But, after that if I go to the user1 home page tab and refresh..it turns into user2 home page,can't able to use two different users simultaneously...

I am new to this... Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't try this because the user have 1 session and the session is on the browser level so your browser will have only 1 session with the name `user` or `user_id`, so if you want to try 2 different users you can do this by using different browser. because there is no case your logged user have 2 accounts in your websites.